# JSLint, when using JS frameworks

Tags: dojo, jslint

I use the Dojo framework, which I load from an url.

How should I deal with the `'dojo' was used before it was defined` errors, and the alike?

Yes, my feeling really get hurt, when running code through JSlint.

Comment: Take JSLint's messages with a grain of salt. Its not perfect (nor is the language). 90% of the time it is correct though.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can put something like

```
/* globals dojo */
```

in the beggining of your file to tell JSLint that dojo exists?

I personaly use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) (a fork of JSLint that is less nitpicky) instead and one of the preconfigured options is support for Dojo.

Comment: Before I knew about this option (or before it was an option, I'm not sure) I wrote a greasemonkey script that bound to the `mousedown` of the "JSLint" button and prepended `var $;` to the top of my code.  Surprisingly it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to put Dojo first in your JavaScript.  The message suggests that you have an ordering problem.

Don't take it personally.  You are not your code.  Just make it better, learn something, and don't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll all the way down to the bottom there is a "predefined" textbox.  Simply put in any of the variables you need into there (comma separated).